# Firebase IOS Crash Reporting with Embedded Framework

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I have a project which contains 3 targets

- The application target
- The Embedded Framework
- The today extension

Which target should I include the Firebase Crash Framework into ?

Currently I have included it into the embedded framework so that both the app and extension might use it.

The problem is that symbol files related to the application are not being uploaded automatically.
How do I get about this ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Firebase Crash SDK inside an Embedded framework and making the framework included in the App and the Today extension should work.

If you want to symbolicate the app related symbols, use the steps mentioned in https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#upload_symbol_files. This will enable the app/extension to have their symbols de-symbolicated.